# Is it important to explicitly declare properties in PHP?

Tags: php

I have followed a tutorial to create a simple blog writing application in PHP and have modified the classes in this tutorial so that they have additional capabilities.  Modifying this very bare bones app has given me a better understanding of how PHP works, however I have run across an interesting situation.

One of the classes in my project has about a half dozen class properties such as `public $id, public $author, public $post`. These properties are declared at the beginning of this class however I find that if I remove all but one of these properties the app still functions correctly.

Is it wrong to remove a property declaration such as `public $datePosted` from the beginning of a class if this class still assigns variables to this property like this: `$this->datePosted = $someVariableName;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you try to *access* a class property which hasn't been declared, PHP will issue a notice:

```
class Foo { }

var $fu = new Foo();
echo $fu->baz;
```

> `Notice: Undefined property: Foo::$baz in blah.php on line 4`

If you set a value first (`$fu->baz = 'blah'`) then it won't complain, but that's not a great situation.

You should definitely declare all your class variables (unless of course you want to have some fun with the [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members))...

Answer (score 8):

it's clearer for anyone reading your code that the members have been explicitly defined as public rather than just defaulting to it because you haven't assigned them as being public members.

Also, `$this->$datePosted` is wrong, it should be like this:

```
$this->datePosted = $someVariable;
```

which may be why you are experiencing an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  $this->$datePosted was a typo that Daok has fixed. It wasn't actually a problem in my code.

Answer (score 6):

PHP is really loose about how it handles class member definitions. You *technically* don't have to declare them. But you *should*, for two big reasons:

- People with smart IDE's (Eclipse, Aptana, Zend Studio) will love if they can take advantage of their editor's code intellisense (auto-complete) while working with your classes. This feature really helps prevent against bugs involving typos. If you don't declare your fields, the IDE has no real way of determining the class' fields.
- Someone just getting done working with a compiled language (C++) will likely send a hitman after you if they see a lack of properly-defined fields. It's just good practice to declare them. There's no reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you remove declaration and the code reads this variable prior to writting to it, you will have an error like

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property:
>   A::$unexistent in C:\temp\test.php on
>   line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined property:
>   A::$unexistent in C:\temp\test.php on
>   line 8