# Do I need to declare a variable before initialise it in PHP constructor

Tags: php

I have a question about variable declare in PHP, I know this question may be little bit stupid. I have the following code

```
<?php
  Class Test{
    function __construct(){
      $this->test = 'helloworkd';
    }
    function test(){
      echo $this->test;
    }
  }
  $test = new Test();
  $test->test();
```

It seems like I can use the **test** variable without declaring it. My question is why the test() method can access the **test** variable? Is the **test** a global variable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not global but it has been creates it as a propery of the class, because you used `$this->`. Its true you dont have to declare a property formally in PHP. **but it is a good idea to declare properties you know you are going to use** as it makes a class more readable to others, and you for that matter 6 months down the line when you want to amend the class

Comment: It's better if you declare it, because it helps IDE autocompletition.

Comment: you can also search about PHP magic methods

Comment: Be aware that this will generate a notice 'Use of undefined constant'.

Comment: Without any explicit visibility keyword properties/methods are considered as public. It's always better you declare it explicitly.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433506/is-it-important-to-explicitly-declare-properties-in-php

Comment: @dios231 I think you are missing the point here? see line `echo test;` in the `test()` method..

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I have a better understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is why the test() method can access the test variable?

PHP unlike some other languages allows you to assign values to variables without first declaring them.  The interpreter will initialize them for you.  This is poor practice because it makes code harder to read and debug, and because it can cause errors if you try to *read* a variable that was never declared:

```
<?php
$nonexistentArray['key'] = 7; //Bad practice, but PHP won't complain
$a = $fakeArray['key']; //Undefined variable error
```

Even in the second case, PHP will continue to execute the rest of the script, but it will complain.

> Is the test a global variable?

No. It lives in the local scope.

```
<?php
function myFunc(){
    //$arr was never declared, but PHP won't complain
    $arr['key'][]=7;
}
myFunc();

//Undefined var error. The $arr that was initialized in myFunc is not global
print_r($arr);
```

A good IDE will complain if you try to use a variable that you never declared. In your case, when in the constructor you do:

```
$this->test = 'helloworkd';
```

PHP will initialize this class property for you. Now the rest of your code can use it, including the `test()` method. If it seems like a global var, it's not. It's a class property.  If you tried to access it as just `test` from outside the class, you would not be able to. You'd have to use the accessor operator `->` in `$test->test` or `$this->test`.

Comment: Thanks. I just did some test based on your answer.<br/>if myFunc() is in a Class context, and $arr['key'][] = 7 changes to $this->arr['key'][], it will create a class property just because of the $this key word, right?

Comment: very nice test :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many "test"! You have asign test="helloworld" in the contructor, so it takes a value for every new Test() is made.

```
$x = new Test();
$y = new Test();

echo $x->test();  //"helloworld"
echo $y->test();  //"helloworld"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare your variable. This makes the code more readable for yourself any any others that see your code.

For example:

```
  <?php
  Class Test {
    public $test;
    function __construct($test){
      $this->test = $test;
    }
    function test(){
      echo $this->test; 
   }
```

So now we have a public variable that is accessible through an instance of this class by calling 
$instance->test;

If you do not want this then you can change public to private or protected
You can read about this here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Whatever you pass as an argument when creating an instance of this class will be assigned to the $test variable.

Answer (score 0):

*My question is why the test() method can access the test variable?*

It can't. It is trying to access a constant `test`, if you want to access the class variable, use `$this->test`.

For example:

```
<?php
echo foo;
```

Will echo out a string "foo" and also spits out a notice:  *Use of undefined constant foo - assumed 'foo' in ...*

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just accept an edit of my question. should be $this->test

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class test{
public $test;   
public function __construct(){
$this->test = 'helloworkd'; 
}
$newtest = new Test();
 echo $newtest->test; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, one should really add an explanation to it.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!